# Invoke-Command and Start-Process Issues

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to execute the following script:

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
Invoke-Command -Computername Localhost -Cred $Cred -Scriptblock {Start "Notepad.exe" -Wait}
```

Well, the notepad comes up no problem as Administrator but it is not visible in the current user's account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not possible to see gui in an interactive session with different credential, it live in another user session.

Workaround:

```
start-process notepad.exe -Credential $Cred
```

Comment: I was using the previously, the only problem I have is that when using the -Wait, I get an Access Denied error and it does not wait.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem with PS Remoting and could not find a way to get an app running under one set of credentials to show up on the interactive desktop of a different user.  I eventually gave up and used SysInternals utility [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) along with its `-i` parameter.